# Blacklist some special characters and allow everything else

Tags: java, regex

i want to blacklist only some special characters(<,>,%,$,^) from a string and allow everything else.
i have been trying some regular expressions but they are not working.for e.g. [^%<>] but its not working.

```
String s = "script";
    if(s.matches("[^%<>\\$]")){
        System.out.println("valid");
    }else{
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
```

please suggest some solution

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: What do you think `s.matches("[^%<>\\$]")` should do and what results you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `i want to blacklist only some special characters(<,>,%,$,^) from a string and allow everything else.`

You can use this regex:

```
^[^%<>^$]+$
```

PS: For using in `String#matches` you don't even line start/end anchors `^ and $` and can use code like this:

```
String s = "script";
if( s.matches("[^%<>^$]+") ) {
    System.out.println("valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("invalid");
}
```

Comment: @skiwi: Inside character class `[ and `] they need not be escaped.

Comment: it should be valid for String s = "<script>"

Comment: See working demo: http://ideone.com/IKuV3R and no `<script>` is invalid because you wrote `blacklist only some special characters(<,>,%,$,^)`

Comment: `<script>` is not valid since it contains the characters you blacklisted.

Comment: but in both case it prints invalid... for e.g: "script" should be valid and "<script> should be invalid. but it shows invalid in both cases

Comment: @anonymous: I am really surprized to read your comment. Did you even see the demo link I provided: above (http://ideone.com/IKuV3R) for `script` it prints `valid` and for `<script>` it prints `invalid`

Comment: @anubhava i m looking at it... n ur code is working.. i am surprised that it wasnt working for me... thankyou... and sorry....

Answer (score 0):

Another example which black lists all these characters:
[ " : * ? < > ^ $ \ | / ]

```
/^[^":*?<>^$\\|\\/]+$/
```